# Can't get cygwin to compile C++ Boost libraries

Tags: c++, boost, cygwin

I'm trying to get up and running with Boost, so I'm trying to compile the simple example problem from Boost's "Getting Started" page. I've had two issues, and I'm not sure they're related (I'm better than a novice, but not by much) but maybe they're related...

1st issue: the "tar --bzip2 -xf /path/to/boost_1_49_0.tar.bz2" command didn't work (yes, I put the correct path in, but it gave me some errors, I forget what they were) so I used "tar -xjvf  " from the directory where boost_1_49_0.tar.bz2 was located. That de-compressed the zip file and I proceeded with the example...

2nd issue: The example.cpp file will not compile, the first statement in the code is #include "boost/lambda/lambda.hpp" but then for every header file lambda.hpp is trying access, there's a "No such file or directory" compile error. For example, here are two (of the six, and I get errors for all 6) header files within lambda.hpp and the errors displayed by the cygwin compiler:

boost/lambda/lambda.hpp:14:33: boost/lambda/core.hpp: No such file or directory
boost/lambda/lambda.hpp:21:52: boost/lambda/detail/operator_actions.hpp: No such file or directory

If it helps, this is the command I'm running to compile (I generally create the executable in a separate -o command):
g++ -c example.cpp

Why can't the system find these? I added the installed directory (path/to/boost_1_49_0) to the PATH variable before I started so I know that's no it. Thanks for any advice...

(I've looked on stackoverflow and there were similar issues, but no solutions that worked)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've already solved the first issue: namely, that you must specify the -j flag on tar to untar a bzip2'd file.

For the second issue, you need to specify boost on your include path, either by specifying it with the [-I command line option](http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/gccintro/gccintro_21.html) or via the [CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH environment variable](http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/gccintro/gccintro_23.html).

Comment: Thanks for the response, but neither approach worked, I'm still getting the same compile errors where it can't find the file or directory.

Comment: I've read up on -I, -L, include path, search path, and how it's necesary to explicitly define your header file locations within these environment variables (CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH). However, I'm still getting the same error(s). In cygwin the PATH variable is the include path variable descibed in the link in the answer. I've included  ...boost/lambda/ to the PATH variable, the CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH variable, and this simple program still chokes on it. Any more help would be greatly appreciated, thanks